# getting Test input to test service layer CRUD operations

Tags: testng, dao, service-layer, testng-dataprovider

I have a service layer with methods to insert data into db, update data and delete data from db, which invoke DAO layer for the definitions of these methods. In the client package, I have a test class, where I get user input for the operations invoking the service layer.

My service class looks as follows:

```
public class Service extends AbstractService {
        public void createEmp(Emp emp) {
            EmpDAO empDao = new EmpDAO();
            empDao.insertEmp(emp);
        } 
        public int updateEmp(int empId, Emp emp) {
            EmpDAO empDao = new EmpDAO();
            int rows_affected = empDao.updateEmp(empId, emp);
            return rows_affected;
        }
        public int deleteEmp(int empId) {
            EmpDAO empDao = new EmpDAO();
            int rows_affected = empDao.deleteEmp(empId);
            return rows_affected;
        }
}
```

and test class looks as follows:

```
public class Application {

    public void insertData(){
        Emp em = new Emp();
        Service service = new Service();

        //insert data into Employee table  
        em.setEmpName("aaaaaa");
        em.setDeptId(2);
        service.createEmp(em); 
    }
    public void updateData(){
        // update employee
        em.setDeptId(2);
        .....
        service.updateEmp(2,em);
        .....           
    }
    public void deleteData()
        //Delete data from Employee table
        service.deleteEmp(2);

    }
}
```

Now I want to write a test class to test my method using TestNG. I don't know how to use `@DataProvider` to give input for the insert operation to invoke it once with more inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Here are 2 methods that provide an example for your `insertData` method, using a `@DataProvider`:

```
@DataProvider(name = "test2")
public static Object[][] insertTestData() {
    return new Object[][] {{"aaaaaa", 2}, {"other", 3}};
}

@Test(dataProvider = "test2")
public void insertData(String empName, Integer deptId){
    Emp em = new Emp();
    Service service = new Service();

    //insert data into Employee table  
    em.setEmpName("aaaaaa");
    em.setDeptId(2);
    service.createEmp(em); 
}
```